# Oracle Apex: Shuttle doesn't put value on the right side and provide null

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I've put LOV on the left hand side but when i choose some of them, and click on creat, it tells me shuttle must have some value, i searched alot on solving this but i couldn't find, it was working so good but now it doesn't.

here's pictures showing the details of the shuttle.

[image]

and here's the process

```
 declare
    tab apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
begin
    tab := apex_util.string_to_table (:P2_RC);
    for i in 1..tab.count loop
        insert into STR_RC(STRID, RCID)
        values
(:HIDDEN_STR_1, tab(i) );
    end loop;
end;
```

HIDDEN_STR_1 is and ID number from another table.

when i press creat, nothing happen to the table i want to insert data in which is STR_RC, and when i change the process to this code,and change the validation to no, it insert nulls in both columns , so please help .

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO STR_RC(STRID,RCID)
     VALUES (:HIDDEN_STR_1 ,:P2_RC);
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the problem wasn't in my shuttle, the problem was in the sequence of processes.

I have reset process which clear session, and have it before my process that shuttle depend on, so i was getting null all the time.

Comment: I see, thanks for sharing part of the solution. However, that doesn't explain why you received validation errors on your shuttle (the ones that indicated a null return value).

Comment: you r right, but i don't get errors now, i switched it to yes and no errors. maybe i had wrong code in sql query ? but now all problems solved

Comment: i found the answer for your question, my creat button was before the shuttle , so when i click on creat, it clear all sessions, so it will ask for a value because creat button cleared all values in the form.

Comment: so i made 2 mistakes , one for the process and one for the creat button

Answer (score 0):

Please take notice that in your first picture you have the items "always required" property set to "yes". This means that if your returned value is null then apex with prevent subsequent processes from executing.

Option 1: Set the always "required property" to "No".
Option 2: ensure that your lov does not return null.

Comment: I turned it off, and checked the data selected in LOV, nothing return null, both columns has value, one has name and the return is a number.

Comment: HIDDEN_STR_1 isn't null and it insert it as a null, i dont know why, i checked my SQL code in process, but nothing changed and i was getting data from the same code. do i've to fill options in source of shuttle ? or null is okay ?

Comment: @Alsqr can you please post images of the hidden_str_1 item similarly to how you posted images of P2_RC?

Comment: it's just a normal hidden button, i tried select list or list manager, same problem , the process doesn't get the values